# How to search date Excel

Tags: excel, date, filter

I have an Excel Spreadsheet that contains 2 active X text boxes as search boxes, that are connected via

`=FILTER(B4:E17,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(I2,D4:D17))*ISNUMBER(SEARCH(G2, B4:B17)),"No Match")`

[image]

The box above name searches the name column just fine, but I want to also be able to refine the date column. Dates were input in the form `april 4, 2022`, which Excel converts to `04-Apr-22`. I can't seem to figure out what format results in a searchable date field. `Apr` doesn't return anything. imputing the number `7` returns `06-Apr-22` and `16-Apr-22`

Can anyone help? Thanks is advance.

Comment: Format should be irrelevant.  Excel stores dates as serial numbers since `1-1-1900`. Assuming that both the data from `G2` and the data in `B4:B17` are "real dates" and not strings that looks like dates, there should be no issues.  If the data being returned in `G2` is not a "real date", you will need to convert it to one. You can either do this on the data input side; or you could do something like `SEARCH(DATEVALUE(G2)...`

Comment: Whether there is an issue depends on the aim. The values in B are indeed serial numbers, which is why `7` returns those two dates (`44657` and `44667`). You can also get a match for `44657` by entering `4-6-22` (even `4-6` will work, but only because Excel 'auto-completes' that entry with the current year; i.e. `4-6` wouldn't match `6-Apr-21`!). Suppose you want to use "Apr" to get all dates in April. This can only be done by converting the serial numbers to strings, e.g. `=TEXT(...,"DD-MMM-YY")` and then overwrite B4:B17.